# Off-shell legs in Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conservation-laws, feynman-diagrams

I have a tree-level diagram with one leg being off-shell (its momentum beeing $\mathcal{O}(m_B)$). How do I treat this leg when computing the amplitude? Do I put in the propagator and ignore the momentum in the denominator?

Comment: Off-shell means, that it does not fulfill the dispersion relation (Klein Gordon equation). As a consequence, your process does not conserve energy and momentum. Thus you insert a momentum in your propagator, but it has no relation to the others.